How can I install Monogame offline?
I have a PC that doesn't have a network card and I can't even connect it to the router via cable, I can only put data on it via a storage drive, for example a USB stick. I installed .net and vscode but I don't know how to install Monogame offline.
I tried to download the source code from github and compile it but I didn't succeed, not even with nuget

Have you tried installing it from one of the nuget packages from a local source? You can also install the package in VSCode locally. I always advise against VSCode for proper C# development and prefer VS, but that's up to you.

Is the storage drive USB?  Because you could get a USB wifi device or if its close to the router they have USB RJ-45 devices too.
